# Implement NavigationDrawer with multiple fragments using MVP pattern

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, navigation-drawer, mvp

I started my new project with the intent to follow `MVP` pattern. I have dealt with a general login, sign up activities. But now I need to implement navigation drawer with `MVP` pattern. I did a research over the internet but I did not get any good reference for implementing this in my application.
Does anyone can suggest me with better ideas or references?

Thanks.

Comment: try this ref: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: I was hoping for navigation drawer using MVP pattern.I have already implemented this drawer in androidhive. Anyway,  thanks for the info.

Comment: I was looking for the right implementation for this also